# Using a SanDisk Ultra Plus 64 GB microSD in a 32gb device

Tags: sd-card

I just purchased a Pyle PLCMDVR8 Dual camera video driving system. It says it will accept 32gb SD card. I have a 64gb SanDisk ultra plus. Will it damage either the Pyle or the SD card to try it in the Pyle?

Answer (score 0):

The chance of any kind of damage is utterly minimal bordering on non-existent. I've tried several cards in "unsupported" devices over the years with no ill effects.

The worst case is that the card simply does not function or appear to the device you are plugging it into. If it doesn't work then remove the card and simply insert it elsewhere.

That said I would be surprised if a 64gb card didn't work, but SD card compatibility is an utter nightmare with all the different specifications and protocol changes that have happened over the years.